# Thunderbird changes file names in Maildir folder

Tags: debian, thunderbird

Whenever I put a mail in my `Maildir/.Send/cur/` folder and I view this email in Thunderbird, suddenly, the file name has changed to something like this:

> 1573421271.M387702P15858.domain.com:2,S

This is fine for me, if not Thunderbird is very inconsistent. Sometimes this doesn't happen.

Is it possible to turn off this feature?
Or, can I figure out the meaning of these numbers? I understand that the first one is the epoch. What about the number after the point?

Thanks

Comment: The "S" flag after the comma is part of the Maildir standard and means "Seen". You can configure Thunderbird so it marks messages as seen automatically or not, or with a delay. It's under "Preferences" > "Display" > "Advanced"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1573421271.M387702P15858.domain.com:2,S

This is actually the [standard file name format](https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html) for messages inside a Maildir.

Names within the `cur` subdirectory are not fully static: the part after `:` is an information/flags field indicating, among other things, whether the message has been *seen* (read), whether it has been replied to or forwarded, and so on.

So Thunderbird needs to rename the file in order to mark the message as 'read'; and if the file previously had some arbitrary name (invalid according to Maildir standards), normally the app ends up generating a new valid name prefix for it as well.

The main part of the name (to the left of `:`) consists of various unique identifiers chosen by the mail app (or generally by the mail *delivery* program, or IMAP server). Their only purpose is to make sure the filename is *unique*, so that multiple deliveries to the same folder will never conflict with each other.

For example, `M387702` is the number of microseconds from the same epoch time, `P15858` is the process ID of the program which performed the delivery, `V<num>` and `I<num>` would be the file's device and inode numbers.

(The spec doesn't say that the prefix has to contain parseable information – it just has to be unique. However, there might be comma-separated [extension fields](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir) providing extra information to some mail services such as Dovecot.)

> Is it possible to turn off this feature?

No. Thunderbird is just following the Maildir format rules.

You can claim that any sufficiently unique prefix is valid – and the format spec would agree – but as soon as the message is moved from `new/` to `cur/` it *must* have the `:2,<flags>` suffix appended.

So e.g. `cur/My Little Message.eml:2,` is a valid name but `cur/My Little Message.eml` alone is not.

- https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html
- https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir